# Macro with a C++ class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, c++17, c++14

I was going through this code (line 41):

https://github.com/black-sat/black/blob/master/src/lib/include/black/logic/parser.hpp

and came across something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define YES

class YES myClass{};

int main(){
cout << "Hi\n";
return 0;
}
```

What is the purpose of defining a macro and using it in front of a class identifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you've written it there isn't much point. But if you look at the project's [common.hpp](https://github.com/black-sat/black/blob/master/src/lib/include/black/support/common.hpp) file to see how it's used, it makes a lot of sense, and is a common pattern in C and C++:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #define BLACK_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define BLACK_EXPORT
#endif
```

...

```
  class BLACK_EXPORT parser
  {
  public:
      ...
```

Here the author has defined compiler-dependent attributes. If the code is built using MSVC, then any class marked with the BLACK_EXPORT macro will get the `dllexport` attribute. For other compilers it will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you see, for example:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class

you'll see that there are a lot of modifiers for a class (for instance, look into the *attr* optional parameter here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

Defining that macro with the required values can adapt the class as required whenever it is included.